# Cannot compile with glossaries on Mac. No language module detected

Tags: texmaker, glossaries, languages, mactex, mac

I'm using TexMaker on Mac. I use glossaries in my document, like this

```
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,toc,numberedsection=autolabel]{glossaries}
\iflanguage{czech}{\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{Seznam pou{\v z}it{\' y}ch zkratek}}{}
\makeglossaries
```

When I try to compile it, I get an error

> No language module detected for 'czech'

I have no idea how to solve this and nothing I found on Google helped me.

For completeness of information, I have OS X Yosemite and I installed LateX with MacTex.

Any ideas

Comment: Please provide a complete example. `glossaries` does not always cause a compilation failure when it fails to find a suitable language module. I see this regularly as a compilation warning as opposed to an error. So obviously your case is different somehow.

Comment: Oh, I see. I wrote it's an error, which was mistake. It's in fact a warning and now I see that the document eventually compiles. I'm sorry, I'm not very experienced with LateX.
So is it ok that it shows me the warning? I mean, the document compiles, so I maybe I shouldn't care, right?

Comment: It just means that standard strings like `List of Acronyms` or `see` or whatever may appear in the wrong language. So check the output to make sure that everything is in Czech. (I'm assuming your document is in Czech.)

Comment: There's currently no `glossaries` support for Czech. There are instructions on creating a new language module in the [Creating a New Language Module](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:newlang) section of the manual.